# How to validate a large number of emails with SendGrid and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sendgrid, email-validation, bulk-email

I have a list of 50k+ email every month addresses that I need to validate using SendGrid'API. I am looking for a way to validate all of the emails at once, rather than sending individual requests for each email.

Can someone provide a Python code snippet or a step-by-step guide on how to use SendGrid's  API to validate a large number of emails in bulk?

I have tried validating emails one by one,
but that takes lot of time,
so i am in search of a way to validate all of emails at one,
to save time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [SendGrid email validation API does not support batch validation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/managing-contacts/email-address-validation) at this time:

> The API currently accepts one email address at a time. If for some
> reason you have multiple addresses you need to validate, please call
> the API once per email address. We do not currently have a batch API.

You'll have to iterate over all your email addresses and validate them one by one.